# Django design question

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a model in django that have a boolean private/public attribute:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want that every-time I query this model in an application it returns only public instances to the common user and all available instances to the super-user.

How and where I need to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You implement that logic at the view layer, probably with a [custom manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets).

Your manager would look something like this:

```
class PublicTestModelManager(models.Manager):
  def get_query_set(self):
    return super(PublicTestModelManager, self).get_query_set().filter(is_public = True)
```

Your model would look something like:

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    public_objects = PublicTestModelManager()
```

You could then write a function that picked the right manager:

```
def test_objects_for_user(user):
  if user.is_superuser:
    return TestModel.objects
  else:
    return TestModel.public_objects
```

Then in your view you could use:

```
test_objects_for_user(request.user).all()
```

Comment: but then I still need to write if/else clause in every view, right?

Comment: Thanks, seems very complicated for me, I though there could be more simple solution)